# How share Angular app between two projects

Tags: angularjs, git

I have an web page that use Angular with own controllers, directives and so on.

I need to create another page, this page must load the same Angular app, the difference between the two project are only the templates.

I don't want update two different project for every single change to the controller.

How is the best solution for share the code between two projects?
And the better way to add it to git (actualy I have only one git repository for app and template of first app)

UPDATE

the app has this structure

```
/var/www/site-a/htdocs/
                      |- index.html
                      |- /app
                      |    |- app.js
                      |    |- directives.js
                      |    |- controllers.js
                      |    |- filters.js
                      |    |- /templates
                      |- /css
                      |- /images
                      |- /bower_components
```

all the code under /app folder (except /templates) are the same
I think there are two ways:

**A) two different apps**

**site A**

```
/var/www/site-a/htdocs/
                      |- index.html
                      |- /app
                      |    |- config.js
                      |    |- /templates
                      |- /css
                      |- /images
                      |- /bower_components
```

**site B**

```
/var/www/site-b/htdocs/
                      |- index.html
                      |- /app
                      |    |- config.js
                      |    |- /templates
                      |- /css
                      |- /images
                      |- /bower_components
```

**site for share app files**

```
/var/www/site-app/htdocs/
                      |- app.js
                      |- directives.js
                      |- controllers.js
                      |- filters.js
```

In this case I have three project on Git, app and controller are the same

**B) one app**

```
/var/www/site-app/htdocs/
                      |- index.html
                      |- /app
                      |    |- app.js
                      |    |- directives.js
                      |    |- controllers.js
                      |    |- filters.js
                      |    |- /templates
                      |             |- /site-a
                      |             |- /site-b
                      |- /css
                      |    |- /site-a
                      |    |- /site-b
                      |- /images
                      |    |- /site-a
                      |    |- /site-b
                      |- /bower_components
```

in this case I have only one git project

**But I have some doubts:**

- how load different CSS into index.html? I need  that differents sites point to different index file?
- how load different template (or config file) per site? Could I have differents settings based on site URLs?

**Which solution is better?**

Comment: If templates map 1:1, which is too good to be true, I'd put HTMLs into two different dirs with same structure and add provider that stores current dir value to get templates from. Two apps will have different thin entry point modules with same dependencies, but different provider config.

Comment: @Klaster_1 could you explain how load different config per site (entry point)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use a variable to link to your templates ?

I haven't try, but maybe is it possible to use :

```
.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    template: linkToTheTemplate
  };
});
```

The same with controller and routes.